# Xcode crashes when creating new Project or Playground

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

When using Xcode 7.0.1 or the latest Xcode Beta (7.1 beta 3) to create a new Project or a new Playground, Xcode crashes with the following error:

> Application Specific Information:
>   Sending goNextOrFinish: to  from 
>   ProductBuildVersion: 7A1001
>   UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): -[NSOpenPanel setAccessoryViewDisclosed:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa7595e9d90
>   UserInfo: (null)

[Full error log](http://pastebin.com/WurxtVLy)

The problem happens when creating a new Project with any of the preset templates (even a new empty project crashes).
It happens with no regards to the language (Swift and Objective-C will crash). Organization name and product name also don't seem to matter.

Opening existing project works without any problem. Saving, Compiling and uploading to real device or simulator works without any problem.

Why does this crash happen and how do I successfully create a new project or Playground?

**Edit 1**
Creating a new file or new playground file in an existing project does function properly. Playground files also execute as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I found some instructions, hoping to help you:

1. Close all open applications
2. Relaunch Finder
3. Run  `sudo find / -name ".DS_Store"  -exec rm {} \;`
4. This removes all old `.DS_Store` files on the computer
5. Launch Finder and set default view to "LIST VIEW" as shown here:
   [How to Set Finder Views for Folders and Sub-Folders](https://www.lifewire.com/set-finder-views-for-folders-and-subfolders-2260912#step2)
6. Rerun the offending application and File Chooser works